# PHP and JS combined

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

I'm trying out this code, it's on WordPress in a loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ID = <?php the_ID(); ?>;
jQuery('#'document.write(ID);' a').click(function () {
    jQuery('#info-'document.write(ID);'').slideToggle('fast', function () {});
});
</script>
```

It's inside a HTML and it just keeps throwing errors, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ID = 1;
jQuery('#1 a').click(function () {
    jQuery('#info-1').slideToggle('fast', function () {});
});
</script>
```

Comment: here you need to enclose it with quotes: `var ID = <?php the_ID(); ?>;` like this `var ID = '<?php the_ID(); ?>';`

Comment: Not if it's an integer

Comment: What errors do you get ? What have you tried to solve them ?

Answer (score 3):

You missed the quotes arround the "the_ID()", but if the ID is an
integer it is ok. Also you had two document.write() where they should not be.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ID = '<?php the_ID(); ?>';
jQuery('#'+ID+' a').click(function () { 
    jQuery('#info-' + ID).slideToggle('fast', function () {});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work well, progress a bit by changing +ID+ to +<?php the_ID(); ?>+, I want them to show like: '#1 a', '#2 a' any idea how to figure out?

Comment: Uhm .. you now an Html-ID may not start with a number?

Comment: I know. :) But it tested it without the PHP, just plain number and it worked. This is just a 'demo' because I don't want to post the original ID's. (because of privacy). I just want the ID to stick to the #. Any way to pass through?

Comment: If you tested it without php and it worked, can you  show the html-source code php generated?

Comment: See the example above.

Comment: which errors is it throwing? Please update your question.